# Neo4j PHP Graphaware '400 Bad Content-Type header' error

Tags: php, neo4j, graphaware

The following test case (assuming correct password)

```
<?php
    require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
    use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;
    $client = ClientBuilder :: create() -> addConnection("default", "http://neo4j:Password@localhost:7474") -> build();
    $query  = "MATCH (u:User)
               RETURN u";
    $result = $client -> run($query);
    $user = $result -> firstRecord() -> values()[0];
?>
```

gives me the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ClientException: Client error: `POST http://neo4j:***@localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit` resulted in a `400 Bad Content-Type header value: ''` response in /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(66): GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Response))
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Response))
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Response), Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(47): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise::GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\{closure}()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(246): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\TaskQueue->run(true)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/ in /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 113, referer: http://localhost/
```

This is the $client when I var_dump it:

```
object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Client)#7 (2) {
  ["connectionManager":protected]=>
  object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\ConnectionManager)#2 (2) {
    ["connections":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\ConnectionManager":private]=>
    array(1) {
      ["default"]=>
      object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection)#4 (5) {
        ["alias":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=>
        string(7) "default"
        ["uri":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=>
        string(38) "http://neo4j:Password@localhost:7474"
        ["driver":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=>
        object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\HttpDriver\Driver)#6 (2) {
          ["uri":protected]=>
          string(38) "http://neo4j:Password@localhost:7474"
          ["config":protected]=>
          object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\HttpDriver\Configuration)#5 (1) {
            ["timeout":protected]=>
            int(5)
          }
        }
        ["session":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=>
        NULL
        ["timeout":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=>
        int(5)
      }
    }
    ["master":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\ConnectionManager":private]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["eventDispatcher":protected]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher)#8 (2) {
    ["listeners":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["sorted":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know how to interpret this or what is wrong.

- My database is running properly in the neo4j browser client.
- As far as I know graphaware is installed appropriately, as per the
  instructions on the website.
- I have tested and the error occurs at the point of running the query,
  not at the point of creating the client (even though this is not
  indicated clearly by the error).
- If I copy / paste the query directly into the neo4j browser client
  then it works as expected.

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: Can you var_dump $client? Also have you tried to update or rollback your guzzle version?

Comment: what content type do you expect? set the header

Comment: @luminoslty thanks, I have added the var_dump info

Comment: @StephanosPapastylianou Is the actual url you're trying to hit localhost? If so have you tried replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: @luminoslty Yes the actual url is localhost and unfortunately 127.0.0.1 doesn't work either...

Comment: does your password contains some special characters  (like @, /, :, ..) ?

Comment: @logisima No just letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [GraphAware PHP Client](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client) you don't seem to use the latest version, so you need to update, **OR** you hit [the empty array bug](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client/pull/100) (e.g. Your problem is that you don't send *Content-Type:application/json*, that seems to only be set using function *prepareRequest* in *GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\HttpDriver\Session*). Also look at your query syntax since it seems to be deprecated in [Install instructions](https://neo4j.com/developer/php/) and in [the developer documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/) for Neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, in my case, the solution was to downgrade PHP from 7.1 to 7.0. This supposes to help You either.

Answer (score 0):

Do install php-curl module and try, it should work.

Discussed here: https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client/issues/142#issuecomment-558857861

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)